# R Markdown Error compiling

Tags: r, latex, markdown

I am trying to write a Latex document with the help of the package R Markdown.
I have always been using software such as TaxMaker, but considering that I will be using R to produce several plots I would like to try the R Markdown package.

So far I have a very simple code just to try and understand it it works. Here there is the document

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
---
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\title{My Title}
\author{Me}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

However this does not compile:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.

Error: Failed to compile 1.tex. See 1.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

The same code works perfectly in a standard Latex environment.

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: I noted that you received good answers to your questions, but rarely accepted these. Hint  .-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using rmarkdown, you do not have to write LaTeX code. Instead you write markdown like this:

```
---
title: "My title"
author: "Me"
date: May 2018
output: pdf_document
---

# Introduction

Some text.
```

[R Markdown: The Definitive Guide](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/) will fill you in on all the details.

Answer (score 1):

In Rmarkdown, the location for custom LaTeX packages is a list in the YAML header `header-includes:`, as is the argument `documentclass:`. The most important packages are already included, so you rarely have to configure them explicitly. Especially in your example, `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` does not seem to work, use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` instead.

```
---
title: "My Title"
author: me
output: pdf_document
documentclass: article
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{hyperref}
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
---

# Header

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

[image]

***Note:*** An extensive collection of LaTeX options can be found in the [Pandoc Manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex).

Comment: The `article` class and these packages are already used by default. No need to specify them in the YAML.

Comment: @RalfStubner Good point! I have now formulated my answer a little less deterministic.